# using data from context before is available

Tags: reactjs

I have an input field that´s rendering data from the context. and it can change the data as well.

```
<input value={ user.name } onChange={(e) => setUser({...user, name: e.target.value})} />
```

when the date doesn´t exist yet I´m getting this warning

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type
>   undefined to be controlled.

only way to fix it is setting name to empty by default

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: ''});
```

but my user is not empty anymore by default (I can´t check if (user) {...} )
how can I use

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({ });
```

without getting the warning? (input should be empty by default. that´s fine)

Comment: The issue isn't with your state but with your control. You're changing it from a controlled input to an uncontrolled input. Provide a default value to your input if state is undefined.

Comment: like value={ user.name || '' } ?

Comment: Yep, that will keep it as a controlled component.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply provide a default value for your `input` element if `user.name` is falsey.

```
<input 
  value={ user.name || "" } 
  onChange={(e) => setUser({...user, name: e.target.value})} 
/>
```